# Most reliable way to detect printer status using c#

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, wmi, printdocument

I am writing an application in which users needs to make sure that the printer is online/working before they print the invoice.

Most of solutions on the internet point to WMI class to query for printers and their properties including PrinterStatus, PrinterState.. etc.

However that method suffers from the problem of returning Idle status all the time (check the [thread here](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/wmi-printerstatus-win32_printer-reliable-t2434571.html)).

So is a way to use WMI to detect if printer is working or not? Or should I use another approach if any exists?

Note: 
An alternative way might be using PrintQueue class, but I am not sure if I can detect the exact print jobs sent by PrintDocument class whcih I am using to print.

Comment: What is the real question? Can you use WMI and C#? Certainly. Are you having trouble with code doing that?

Comment: If the printer is 'idle' is should be working fine.
The only other way i can think of, is checking if the ip address responds (which is basically the same as idle) - or actually printing something to it like a test page and keep a check on the printqueue - but apart from that, there isn't anything else i believe

Comment: @ Daniel B: The question is what is the best way to detect printer status, since WMI seems not to be reliable as far as I can see. I've already written the code, but it's always giving me idle status.

Comment: @Alex Carlsen: I turned the printer off and it kept giving me idle status. I need a better way to check if printer is ready or not.

Comment: How can I ping a printer?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I'm guessing it's directly connected - well in that case ->
Have you looked at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162861%28v=vs.85%29.aspx - print spooler api?